# How to move a file to a restricted (hidden) location using the command line?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to move a particular file to the restricted location `/home/irshad/.local/share/Steam/Backups` (I cannot access the `.local` folder since I cannot see it in the file manager). Can anyone provide me
the terminal command to do that?

Comment: the folder should not be restricted

Comment: i cant access .local folder

Comment: it is hidden by default, press ctrl + h to make visible

Comment: excellent..........thx............works like charm...thx to u both @JacobVlijm & kaSiya

Comment: perfect, great that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mv` command like this

```
mv /path/to/YOUR_FILE /home/irshad/.local/share/Steam/Backups/
```

If your file name or directory name has a space in its name quote its path:

```
mv "/path/to/YOUR FILEorDIRECTORY" "/home/irshad/.local/share/Steam/MY Backups/"
```

Comment: should it be like this? 
"mv /media/irshad/7650B08250B04B1F/Dota 2/home/irshad/.local/share/Steam/Backups"

Comment: @gambler420 Is your file `Dota 2` (with space in it)??

Comment: yes and its a folder

Comment: @gambler420 Then use this `mv "/media/irshad/7650B08250B04B1F/Dota 2" /home/irshad/.local/share/Steam/Backups/`

Comment: Thx...........big time.....works like a charm.........

Comment: @gambler420 You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you try the mv command and it says "Permission Denied" then use the sudo su command and then try it.